# Write a triple integral, using cylindrical coordinates, for volume of the solid that lies in the intersection of: $y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+z^2=z$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Write a triple integral, using cylindrical coordinates, for volume of the solid that lies in the intersection of: $y^2+z^2=1$ and $x^2+z^2=z$.

$x^2+z^2=z$ is the same as $x^2+(z-\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{1}{4}$. To be honest I have no idea how to do this; I could only come with this which I saw from the picture $\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq z \leq \frac{1}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-x^2}$, now that I have to use cylindrical coordinates I do not know what to do with $x$ and $y$, if the $z$ part is even correct.. When I project it to $xy$ plane I get this weird equation: $ x^2+1-y^2=\sqrt{1-y2}$

Comment: The order of integration $\mathrm{d}y\mathrm{d}z\mathrm{d}x$ looks most convenient. If we apply cylindrical coordinates in the $xz-$plane we get $$\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\sin(\theta)} \int_{-\sqrt{1-z^2}}^{\sqrt{1-z^2}}\mathrm{d}yr\mathrm{d}r\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solid formed by intersection of two cylinders.
The cylinders are $x^2 + z^2 \leq z$ and $y^2 + z^2 \leq 1$. Please note that the first cylinder forms only for $z \geq 0$.

For integration, it is easier to take the projection of cylinder $x^2 + z^2 \leq z$ in xz plane and find limits of $y$. So we define the cylindrical coordinates as,

$x = r \cos\theta, z = r \sin\theta, y = y$

$x^2 + z^2 \leq z \implies r^2 \leq r \sin\theta$

i.e, $r \leq \sin\theta, 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi$

$y^2 + z^2 \leq 1 \implies - \sqrt{1-z^2} \leq y \leq \sqrt{1-z^2} $

Finally the integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\sin\theta} \int_{-\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\theta}}^{\sqrt{1-r^2\sin^2\theta}} r ~ dy ~ dr ~ d\theta$